ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
I'm using the Binance API to consume websocket data and send it to my own websocket server. However, the host keeps closing the connection all the time
import asyncio
import itertools
import json
import websockets
from unicorn_binance_websocket_api import BinanceWebSocketApiManager
from src.binance_wrapper import BinanceAPI

connected_clients = set()
client = BinanceAPI()
symbols = client.get_symbols()


def split_seq(iterable, size):
    it = iter(iterable)
    item = list(itertools.islice(it, size))
    while item:
        yield item
        item = list(itertools.islice(it, size))


async def forward_messages(websocket, path):
    connected_clients.add(websocket)
    try:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    finally:
        connected_clients.remove(websocket)


manager = BinanceWebSocketApiManager(exchange="binance.com-futures", output_default="UnicornFy", high_performance=True, warn_on_update=True, ping_timeout_default=3)


def handle_message(message):
    for _client in connected_clients:
        asyncio.ensure_future(_client.send(json.dumps(message)))


chunks = list(split_seq(symbols, 20))
for chunk in chunks:
    manager.create_stream(['kline_1m', 'kline_5m', 'kline_15m', 'kline_1h', 'kline_4h'], chunk, process_stream_data=handle_message)


async def start_server():
    async with websockets.serve(forward_messages, 'localhost', 8765):
        await asyncio.Future()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(start_server())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        manager.stop_manager_with_all_streams()
        loop.close()


I'm getting this error:
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-300836' coro=<WebSocketCommonProtocol.send() done, defined at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py:580> exception=ConnectionClosedError(Close(code=1002, reason='WebSocket Protocol Error'), Close(code=1002, reason='WebSocket Protocol Error'), True)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 635, in send
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 944, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: received 1002 (protocol error) WebSocket Protocol Error; then sent 1002 (protocol error) WebSocket Protocol Error

After this error occurs, the connection is closed and the client must self-reconnect.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
